# Prevent change filename when file exists

Tags: django

I want to display default avatar, but when I try to keep it in a database file it is copied with new name.
How can I prevent change of file name if the file already exists?

My code:
models.py

```
class UserAccount(User):
    contacts = models.OneToOneField('self', null = True)
    isBanned = models.BooleanField(_('ban status'), default = False,
        help_text = _("Display is contact banned by user."))
    avatar = FileField(upload_to = 'avatars')
   objects = UserManager()
```

views.py

```
user = UserAccount.objects.get(username = user_login)
user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
user.email = request.POST['email']
try:
    file = request.FILES['avatar']
    fileName = request.FILES['avatar'].name
except:
    fileName = 'static/avatars/default.gif'
    file = File(open(fileName, 'r'))
user.avatar.save(fileName, file)
user.save()
```

Comment: solved:    user.avatar = 'avatars/default.gif'

Comment: if you solved the problem, post the solution and accept it. StackOverflow encourages question askers giving solution to their own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in the fact that I did not save the avatar, but simply appropriates FileField path to the default avatar.

```
try:
    file = request.FILES['avatar']
    fileName = request.FILES['avatar'].name
except:
    user.avatar = 'avatars/default.gif'
    flag = False
if flag:
    user.avatar.save(fileName, file)
user.save()
```